# Configuring electrum wallet with command line only

Tags: wallet, electrum, development, ubuntu, server

I successfully installed electrum on an ubuntu server using the first ref from google search. But how I can configure it without GUI I didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can configure it without GUI

Maybe

```
electrum -o setconfig ...
```

For example,

- https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ssl.html
- https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsonrpc.html

etc

Comment: Thanks for your participation. But i'm afraid i can't do it using official docs. There are not any real examples which i could adopt.

Answer (score 0):

```
electrum setconfig <key> <value>
```

You can find a list of config keys here:

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/033ad0feb9baf4dd080fadd784bad2bf8fd1e92b/electrum/simple_config.py#L840